# Print json to string

Tags: php, html, json

I have to write json result in a string.

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <form method="POST">
             Enter Pin <input type="text" name="pinCode">
             <input type="submit" name="formSubmit">
         </form>
     </body> </html>


 <?php

     if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
     {
         $input = $_POST['pinCode'];
         $shortUrl=file_get_contents("https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/uiin/indian-city-by-postal-code?project-app-key=<app_key>&pin=".$input);
         $res = json_decode($shortUrl, true);

         echo implode($res);
     }

 ?>
```

Currently the outcome is on json format. I have to print the result in string. e.g - { "title" : "Mr", "name" : "sandeep"}. Result would be like "Mr sandeep". That's why I have used json_decode for changing json into array but then I couldn't understand how to change associative array in string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: json result in a string? what you actually wan to achieve. put some input data and expected outcome based on tat input to make yourself clear to us

Comment: Currently the outcome is on json format. I have to print the result in string. e.g - { "title" : "Mr", "name" : "sandeep"}. Result would be like "Mr sandeep"

Answer (score 1):

Don't decode the json if you want it in string. The output is string and you are converting it to array using json_decode so just comment that line

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
    $input = $_POST['pinCode'];
    $shortUrl=file_get_contents("https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?project-app-key=<app_key>&pin=".$input);
    //$res = json_decode($shortUrl, true);

    echo $shortUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but currently the outcome is on json format. I have to print the result in string. e.g - { "title" : "Mr", "name" : "sandeep"}. Result would be like "Mr sandeep". That's why I had used json_endcode for changing json in array and then I coudn't understand that how to print associative array in string.

Comment: Can provide the json format and the desired output from that